# Trouble removing an element from an array

Tags: javascript

I started self teaching myself JavaScript a couple of weeks ago and have run into a problem I am unable to solve. The program works by allowing a user to enter a list of names which is saved in an array and also shown on the screen as li elements. The program will then randomly select one of the people entered. My problem occurs when trying to remove a person from the list. I am able to remove them from the HTML but not from the array. I have attempted to use the `.splice` method as shown below but this only removes the last element in the array. I believe this to be due to `indexOf(li.value)` not being suitable for this use but do not know what else to try. Any help is much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Student Randomiser</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="myHeading">Student Randomiser</h1>
    <div class="list">
      <p class="description">Add Students:</p>
      <input type="text" class="studentName" value="Write Students Here">
      <button class="addStudent">Add student</button>
      <ul id= "listStudentNames">
      </ul>
      <button class="randomStudent">Select a random student</button>
</div>
<script src="randomNamePicker.js"></script>
</body>
</html>




const addStudent = document.querySelector('button.addStudent');
const studentName = document.querySelector('input.studentName');
const randomStudent = document.querySelector('button.randomStudent');
const listStudentNames = document.querySelector("ul");
let students = [
]
let number
window.onload=function(){
addStudent.addEventListener('click', addStudentToList);
randomStudent.addEventListener('click', selectRandomStudent);
listStudentNames.addEventListener("click", removeStudent);
}
function addButtons(li){
  let remove =document.createElement('button');
  remove.className= "removeStudent";
  remove.textContent = "Remove Student";
  li.appendChild(remove)
}

function removeStudent (){
  if (event.target.tagName === "BUTTON") {
let li = event.target.parentNode;
let ul = li.parentNode;
let i = students.indexOf(li.value);
students.splice(i,1);
ul.removeChild(li);
  }}

function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  number =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function addStudentToList() {
  students.push(studentName.value);
  var ul = document.getElementById("listStudentNames");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(studentName.value));
  addButtons(li);
  ul.appendChild(li);
  studentName.value = "";
}

function selectRandomStudent(){
getRandomIntInclusive(0, students.length);
alert(students[number]);
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged it? Are there any consoles errors? What is the value of `i`?

Comment: Are you sure that your functions are being evoked? Do you have any event listeners on the button click events? If so, I would recommend adding them here. Also, it would be helpful to document what parts of your code belong to which files via a comment.

Comment: @MikeLawson No console errors. I have attached the whole code so hopefully it will be easier to understand. Apologies if it is a mess, as I mentioned I am just starting out so just putting this together has been a challenge for me.

Comment: See my updated answer below for a complete description and working example of your scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a variety of issues with your code, some are programmatic, some are stylistic and some are your logic.

Your main issue is that the only elements that have a `value` property are form elements. So, when you write:

```
let i = students.indexOf(li.value);
```

You have an issue because you set `li` up to be the parent node of `event.target`. `event.target` is the element that initiated the event, in this case a `<button>` and the parent of the button is `<div>`, which (again) doesn't have a `value` property and is not the correct element anyway.

This value is what you are basing your `splice` on. Instead, you need to get the index position of the `li` within the list of `li` elements or the array (they should be the same).

Next, you don't really have a need for an array in this scenario in the first place since all of the student names will be elements within a `<ul>` element, this means that they can be accessed via a "node list", which is an "array-like" object that supports a `length` property, is enumerable and indexable. Keeping the `<li>` element content in a synchronized array doesn't add any value here and makes the overall task more complex that it need be because you are forced to keep the HTML list in sync with the array.

Having said all of this, here's a working example of what you are attempting, with comments inline to explain why my code differs from yours.

```js
// When the DOM is loaded and all elements are accessible...
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

  // Get references to the DOM elements needed to solve problem
  // Using "var" here is perfectly acceptable as their scope will
  // be the entire parent function, which is what we want. Get all
  // these references just once so we don't have to keep scanning
  // the DOM for them each time we want to work with the list.  Also,
  // name your variables "noun"-like names when they refer to elements
  var btnAdd = document.querySelector(".addStudent");
  var btnRandom = document.querySelector(".randomStudent");
  var list = document.getElementById("listStudentNames");
  var student = document.querySelector("input[type='text']");
  var output = document.querySelector(".report");
  
  // Set up an empty array to keep the synchronized student list in
  var students = [];

  // Set up click event handling functions
  btnAdd.addEventListener("click", addStudent);
  btnRandom.addEventListener("click", getRandomStudent);
  
  function addStudent(){
    // Make sure there was valid input
    if(student.value.trim() === ""){ return; }
  
    // Create a new <li> element
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    
    // Set new element up with a click event handler that will
    // cause the current element to be removed from the list
    li.addEventListener("click", removeStudent);
  
    // Populate the element with the text from the <input>
    // The element gets raw text set with the .textContent property
    // while content of form elements is gotten with the "value" 
    // property
    li.textContent = student.value;
    
    // Update the list id's to match the array indexes
    sync();
  
    // Add the element to the end of the <ul>'s list elements
    list.appendChild(li);
    
    // Add new student to the array:
    students.push(student.value);
    
    // Clear value from input
    student.value = "";
    
    logResults();
  }

  function getRandomStudent(){
    console.clear();
    
    if(students.length){
      // Use the built-in JavaScript Math object to get a random number
      // between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive) then multiply that
      // number by the lenght of the <li> node list to get a random
      // number between 0 and the amount of elements in the array
      var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.children.length);
      console.log("Random student is: " + list.children[random].textContent);
    } else {
      console.log("No students to choose from!");
    }
  }

  function removeStudent (evt){
  
    // Re-sync the indexes of the HTML elements to match the array
    sync();
  
    // Remove corresponding student from array first...
    console.clear();
    console.log("Student " + evt.target.id + " about to be removed");
    students.splice(+evt.target.id, 1);
  
    // Every event handling function automatically gets a reference
    // to the event that triggered the function sent into it. We can
    // access that event to get a reference to the actual DOM object
    // the caused the event to be triggered with "event.target"
    list.removeChild(evt.target); 
    
    logResults();
  }
  
  // We have to keep the HTML element indexes in sync with the array indexes
  function sync(){ 
    // Loop through the HTML elements and give them an id that corresponds
    // to the index position of its counterpart in the array.
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(list.children, function(el, index){
       el.id = index;
    });
  }
  
  // This is just a function for updating the display to show the contents
  // of the array to confirm that it is in sync with the list
  function logResults(){
    output.innerHTML = "Array now contains: <br>" + students.join("<br>");
  }

});
```

```css
.list, .report { float:left; }
.report { background-color:aliceblue; }
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <input type="text" class="studentName" placeholder="Enter Student Name Here">
  <button class="addStudent">Add student to list</button>  
  <ul id= "listStudentNames">
  </ul>
  <p class="description">(Click on a student to remove them from the list.)</p>
  <button class="randomStudent">Select a random student</button>
</div>
<div class="report"></div>
```